# Recursively finding with AWK

Tags: bash, shell, awk, pattern-matching

I've got a file that looks like this:

```
$cat myfile.dat

Number of reps:     nrep=  19230
flop count:         nops=  4725964800.

Clock resolution is  4.7619047619047619E-4 , usecs
time =  7.18247611075639725E-6
calc      0: time=    2.902 Gflop/s=    1.629 error=         0.00000000
calc    201: time=    1.186 Gflop/s=    3.985 error=         0.00000000
Number of reps:     nrep=  13456
flop count:         nops=  4234564800.

Clock resolution is  3.7619047619047619E-4 , usecs
time =  7.18247611075639725E-6
calc      0: time=    1.232 Gflop/s=    2.456  error=         0.00000000
calc    201: time=    3.186 Gflop/s=    1.345  error=         0.00000000
```

I am interested to filter just what I need :`nrep`,`time` and `Gflop/s` but this last two only of the line starting with `calc   201`.

So far I've managed to filter what I want, except the elements `time` and `Gflop/s`. This is what I've done:

```
awk -F'= ?' '/nrep=/||/time=/||/Gflop/{print $2}' myfile.dat

19230
2.902 Gflop/s
1.186 Gflop/s
13456
1.232 Gflop/s
3.186 Gflop/s
```

This is obviosly wrong. What I would need, ideally in columns instead is:

```
19230 1.186 3.985
13456 3.186 1.345
```

Is there a reasonbale way of doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `GNU awk` you would simply do:

```
$ awk 'NR>1{print $2,$27,$29}' RS='Number of reps:' file
19230 1.186 3.985
13456 3.186 1.345
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
awk '/Number of reps:/ { printf "%s ", $NF } /calc *201:/ { print $4,$6 }' myfile.dat
```

Answer (score 1):

This script will do what you want:

```
$ awk '/nrep=/{printf "%s ",$5}$1=="calc"&&$2=="201:"{print $4, $6}' myfile.dat 
19230 1.186 3.985
13456 3.186 1.345
```

It prints the fifth word of the lines containing "nrep=", (with no newline afterwards), and then prints the fourth and sixth words of the lines having the first word "calc" and the second "201:"